# Is it possible to change the permission on files in an Android app's internal storage?

Tags: android, file-permissions

I downloaded a file with an app and stored it inside of its internal storage, but the file is set with `-rw-------` and I want to change those permissions so is it possible? I know that using external storage is an option but I want to know if I can do it with internal storage too. Thanks for the help.

Edit:
If it turns out that I can't change the permission is there some shared region of internal storage that I could use? I would like to not force the Android device user to have an SD card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the follow bit of code will change the permissions on the file based on what you set the second parameter to be.

```
FileOutputStream fileOutput = openFileOutput("myApp.apk", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
```

The four options for the second parameter are: `MODE_PRIVATE`, `MODE_APPEND`, `MODE_WORLD_READABLE`, and `MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE`.

Comment: Meanwhile, `Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE` and `Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE` are deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Internal storage is always private to your application.